# How to copy and randomize copied elements in the same loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, random

I'm try to copy the even numbers in an array and randomize the newly copied element inside the same for loop:

```
var arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var arr2=[];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i]%2==0){
    arr2.splice(Math.random()*arr2.length,0,arr[i]);
  }
}
document.write(arr2);
```

The concept is simple: insert the newly copied element at random position of the new array, but the serval output indicates it's not correct:

```
2,6,4,8,0
4,8,6,2,0
6,2,8,4,0
```

which always have 0 at the last. What's wrong with the code? Or is my concept wrong?

Comment: You don't need to loop. You can just use `.filter(), .sort(), and Math.random()` in *one* neat line of code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134857/how-to-copy-and-randomize-copied-elements-in-the-same-loop/41135606#answer-41135606

Comment: Get a list of even indices (easy). [Shuffle that list randomly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/223424). Then use these indices to access the source array while copying. This method guarantees that each element is copied, and no element overwrites another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a scopedShuffle function:

```
function scopedShuffle(a){
  var n = a.slice(), l = n.length;
  n.sort(function(b, c){
    return 0.5 - Math.floor(Math.random()*(l+1))/l;
  });
  return n;
}
van resultArray = scopedShuffle(yourArrayHere);
```

The key here is the scoped use of `n` where `var n = a.slice()`, this way the original Array does not get changed.

I would use a Constuctor, though:

```js
function ShuffleMaster(inputArray){
  var a = inputArray;
  if(!(a instanceof Array)){
    throw new Error('inputArray must be an Array');
  }
  this.getInputArray = function(){
    return a;
  }
  this.setInputArray = function(inputArray){
    if(!(inputArray instanceof Array)){
      throw new Error('inputArray must be an Array');
    }
    a = inputArray;
    return this; // allows for daisy-chaining
  }
  this.shuffle = function(){
    var n = a.slice(), l = n.length;
    n.sort(function(b, c){
     return 0.5 - Math.floor(Math.random()*(l+1))/l;
    });
    return n;
  }
}
var myArray = [0, 7, 21, 26, 78, 756];
var sM = new ShuffleMaster(myArray);
console.log(sM.shuffle()); console.log(sM.shuffle());
console.log(sM.setInputArray([4, 5, 85, 46, 11]).shuffle());
console.log(sM.getInputArray());
```

Here's a simple closure style, where a Self-executing function scopes off the new Array, so it can be accessed upon the next call without passing the original argument... almost static like.

```js
var scopedShuffle = (function(){
  var a;
  return function(inputArray){
    if(inputArray){
      a = inputArray.slice();
    }
    var n = a.slice(), l = n.length;
    n.sort(function(b, c){
      return 0.5 - Math.floor(Math.random()*(l+1))/l;
    });
    return n;
  }
})();
console.log(scopedShuffle(['a', 2, 4, 'g', 'apes']));
console.log(scopedShuffle()); console.log(scopedShuffle());
console.log(scopedShuffle(['learning', 'you', 'now', 'are', 'monkeys', 42, 'life', 'itself', 'the Universe']));
console.log(scopedShuffle()); console.log(scopedShuffle());
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between 0, inclusive, and 1, **exclusive**. Which means `Math.random()*arr2.length` will always be *less* than `arr2.length`, so no element will ever be spliced into the end of the array - except on the first iteration of your loop when the new array is empty so `0` ends up as its first and only element. But subsequent iterations insert to a random position anywhere other than at the end, thus always pushing the `0` to the right.

You can fix it by changing `Math.random()*arr2.length` to `Math.random() * (arr2.length + 1)`.

Note also that `.splice()` doesn't seem to care if you pass it a number that isn't an integer, but for neatness I'd prefer to use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr2.length + 1))`.

Demo:

```js
function makeArray() {
  var arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  var arr2=[];
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
      arr2.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr2.length+1)), 0, arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr2;
}
                  
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple solution:** Long chain of methods (`slice`,`filter`,`sort`).

First use `.slice(0)` to clone, then `.filter()` to filter  to out the odd numbers, finally use `.sort` and `Math.random()` to randomly shuffle.

```
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(a) {
  return (a % 2) === 1; // Return true if a is even
}).sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
};
```

See example:

```js
function shuffleIt() {
  var arr = document.getElementById('numberlist').value.split(' ');
  var arr2 = arr.filter(function(a){return a%2 === 0}).sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = arr2.join(',');
}
```

```html
Type a list of numbers (separate with spaces)
<input type="text" id="numberlist" value="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"/>
<button onclick="shuffleIt()">Shuffle evens (click multiple times to get different results) </button>
<br/>
<b>Output:</b>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Verbose explanation:**

1. `.filter()` calls a callback function passed to it on each element of the array. If the function returns true, it preserves the element; if false, it removes it. `a % 2 === 0` is a condition to check whether a is even or not, so this removes all non-even numbers. This method does not mutate the array and instead returns a new array.

   > The filter() method creates *a new array* with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

2. `.sort` sorts the array. It compare two items at a time, deciding which one goes before the other using the sign of a number returned fro ma function:

> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
>   If compareFunction(a, b) [the callback function passed in] returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
>   If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
>   compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

As you can see, the sign of the returned number determines which array item comes first. `(0.5-Math.random())` randomly returns a positive or negative number (technically 0 might be possible, but very unlikely), therefore sorting the array randomly. *Note: this function mutates the array, but we created a new array using `.filter()`, so the original is still untouched.*